# Binding multiple events to an element in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Here is my component's template

```
<input #emailId (focusout)="emailIdCheck(emailId.value)" #emailIDD (keydown.tab)="emailIdCheck(emailIDD.value)" type="text" placeholder="Your Email ID">
```

As you can see I have bound the `focusout` event as well as `keydown.tab (tab keydown)` event to a method in my component class.

But this looks ugly and does not scale well if I want to bind a number of events.

Is there a possibility to have something like the below?

```
<input #emailId (focusout|keydown.tab)="emailIdCheck(emailId.value)" type="text" placeholder="Your Email ID">
```

Disclaimer: I started practicing angular2 couple of weeks back and am still new

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6675

Oct 3 2016

> not planned in a near future

Comment: I saw they closed the issue, but we still don't have this feature. Someone knows any news about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
<input #email (blur)="emailIdCheck(email.value)" (keydown.tab)="email.blur()" type="text" placeholder="Your Email ID">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).